# Java program that concatenates the contents of several files into one file...?

Tags: java

I'm writing a java program that I'm running on the CMD line that copies several .txt files into one. For example I have three .txt files that I created. Chapter1.txt, chapter2.txt Chapter3.txt. All the contents of these files needs to be copied to book.txt. I ran the code and it ran fine until I entered the command.

*java CatFiles chapter1.txt chapter2.txt chapter3.txt book.txt*

The book.txt file is created but only the contents of one file are copied and I get this error code

```
java.land.illeglStateException: Scanner 
      at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(unknown Source)
      at java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(unknown Source)
      at java.util.Scanner.hasNextLine(unknown Source)
      at CatFiles.main(CatFiles.java)
```

Here's my code

```
public class CatFiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Usage: CatFiles sourcefile1 sourcefile2 . . . targetfile");
            return;
        }
        String target = args[args.length - 1];
        FileReader reader = null;
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(target);
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length - 1; i++) {
            String source = args[i];
            reader = new FileReader(source);
        }
        Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);
        while ( in .hasNextLine()) {
            try {
                String line = in .nextLine();
                out.println(line);
            } finally { in .close();
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Scanner` is not the correct thing to be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the `while` loop inside of the `try block` and not the contrary. Otherwise you're closing the `Scanner` at the first loop and you can not use it anymore. Close your `Scanner` once you're never using it again.

I honestly think correct indentation would have helped here.

---

### JavaDoc

> Throws:
>  `NoSuchElementException` if no line was found
>   **`java.lang.IllegalStateException` if this scanner is closed**

### Solution

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(reader);
try{
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = in.nextLine();
      out.println(line);
    }
} finally {
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: Would a `try` `catch` work as well or would you think the `try` `while` works better in this situation?

Comment: In this situation, you normally wouldn't have to catch something. So your try..finally block is OK, since you only need the finally to close the streams for sure.

Comment: `Scanner` is the wrong thing to be using, `ByteStreams.copy()` from Guava is a one line solution.

Comment: Well, that seemed to fix the error but instead of copying all three files ('chapter1-chapter3') into  'book.txt'  it only copies chapter 3 and not the rest. What could be causing this?

Comment: @Noah Because at the end of the `for` loop, reader will just read the third file. But If you have an answer for this question, accept it and ask a new one so that you do not mix problems.

Comment: @YassinHajaj, Jazaka'allah for the answer, I will accept it since it did fix my error.

Comment: @Noah wa iyaki. Thanks :)

Comment: Well, @JarrodRoberson your answer is too complicated than it needed to be (for a beginner anyway)

Comment: The answers on Stackoverflow are **not just for you**, they are for everyone coming after you that wants to know how to do the same thing correctly. If you want to do it wrong, great, but that approach will end an interview pretty quick in the real world.

Comment: Well, I originally only wanted a fix to my error (which was already solved) I don't want just the answer so that's why I accepted this answer. I'm new to Java so I want to learn to fix errors and **Yassin**, and **Age** helped in finding why I was getting the errors. I do appreciate your answer though. And I'm learning Java as a hobby not for an **interview**

Answer (score 2):

Use this (note: checks about arguments are left as an exercise):

```
public static void main(final String... args)
{
    final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(list, args);

    final Path dstFile = Paths.get(list.remove(list.size() - 1));

    try (
        final OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(dstFile);
    ) {
        for (final String s: list)
            Files.copy(Paths.get(s), out);
    }
}
```

Comment: @fge, Could you edit my code so I can see how it would look? I tried the other answer but it only copies one file not all three

Comment: @Noah just take the code I wrote as is; it should just work.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(args)` will create a `List<String>` from the `String[]` in one step.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson but you cannot remove any elements from such a `List`. This is why I used an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I would argue that you should not be mutating the list to begin with. Teaching beginners to not start bad habits is easier than teaching "experienced" beginners to stop bad habits.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson this list is only visible from this very method so no harm done ;)

Answer (score 0):

#### Idiomatic Solution using Guava:

This includes basic error checking on valid number of arguments. This does not do robust idiomatic exception handling for brevity and scope control.

This solution also uses `Immutable` data throughout making it immune to logic errors because of side effects and state mutation.

#### [Q33846584.java](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q33846584.java)

*Import statements are available in the link above.*

```
public class Q33846584
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        checkArgument(args.length > 2, "You must supply at least 3 file paths as arguments dest, src, src, ...");
        final List<Path> paths = Lists.transform(Arrays.asList(args), new Function<String, Path>()
        {
            @Nullable @Override public Path apply(@Nullable String input)
            {
                return Paths.get(checkNotNull(input));
            }
        });

        final Path destination = paths.get(0);
        try (final OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destination.toFile()))
        {
            for (final Path p : paths.subList(1, paths.size()))
            {
                if (p.toFile().exists())
                {
                    System.out.format("Reading %s and writing to %s", p.toAbsolutePath(), destination.toAbsolutePath());
                    final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(p.toFile());
                    ByteStreams.copy(fis, fos);
                    System.out.println();
                }
                else
                {
                    System.err.format("%s does not exist skipping!", p.toAbsolutePath());
                    System.err.println();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Without Guava:

1. You would have to implement the transformation of the `String[]` yourself in a imperative loop which is straightforward.
2. You would have to implement copying the `InputStream` to the `OutputStream` which is well documented on the internet in general but is basically boilerplate code. You will end up with a possibly buggy or inefficient version of what Guava does. It would only be useful as a learning exercise at best.

*Both of these activities are easy to find on Stackoverflow and are left as exercises for the reader.*